# Change commiter author name

Tags: git

I need SOS help, I committed a project to bitbucket and committed by my name but I need to change the author name (and the email address).

[image: bitbucket]

What's the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the author and committer name and e-mail of multiple commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-to-change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-gi)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+change+commit+email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply amend your last commit and push (forced)

```
git commit --amend --author="Your name <yourEmail@example.com>"
git push --force
```

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56724846/change-commiter-author-name/56724874?noredirect=1#comment100009747_56724874) by [OznOg], if `git config user.name` and `git config user.email` are showing the right values, a [`--reset-author`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---reset-author) is enough:

```
git commit --reset-author 
git push --force
```

---

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
```

So the latest commit on BitBucket is not the latest locally: you have made two other commits.

First check if you can reset the one from bitbucket.

```
git checkout -b tmp
git reset --hard origin/master
git commit --amend --author="Your name <yourEmail@example.com>"
git push --force
```

If what you see if OK, then you can apply your two next commit:

```
git cherry-pick tmp~1
git commit --amend --author="Your name <yourEmail@example.com>"

git cherry-pick tmp
git commit --amend --author="Your name <yourEmail@example.com>"

git push
```

Comment: @OznOg True. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: After I run the first line it tells I have conflicts, how to fix?

Comment: @Devy Did you made any git pull between the time you have pushed and now? Do you have any work in progress? What is the output of `git status`?

Comment: Output of `git status` is:  

On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: Hi, when I run the cherry pick command I get `error: Cherry-picking is not possible because you have unmerged files.`

Comment: @Devy check your git status first: as long as it is not "clean", as long as it lists files with possible conflicts, you should not cherry-pick.