# Delete a branch or rename old author git

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to change/delete the second author name , I have the following in bitbucket:

[image]

, how do I

1. changing the name of this branch (I think it's a branch called tmp)
2. deleting this specific brach (but keep the other code)

I need one of this two, the easiest between them, thanks.

I only want to delete my name from this project

Comment: Are you helping your friend cheat on a school assignment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change commiter author name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56724846/change-commiter-author-name)

Comment: That's previous question is for changing the last commit, here it's a different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have followed [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56724874/6309), you did not need that `tmp` branch anymore.

That was a local marker in order to be able to cherry-pick those commits, before amending them in the master branch.

You can now delete the [`tmp` branch locally and remotely (if you have pushed `tmp`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/6309):

```
git push --delete origin tmp
git branch -d tmp
```

If you have not pushed `tmp`, the first command will fail: you can ignore that.

You won't see `tmp` anymore.